# Why doesn't my contact form work?

Tags: contact

My contact form is here

http://wordswithfriends.net/?page_id=124

When users submit a message, I receive an e-mail but the spinning waiting sign keeps on spinning and the user does not receive confirmation.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What code or plugin are you using for that contact form?

Comment: You're not showing any code for us to evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Contact 7 Help](http://contactform7.com/faq/#The_spinning_arrow_icon_shows_up_once_I_submit_a_form):

> The spinning arrow icon shows up once
>   I submit a form, but then nothing
>   happens.
>
> This is most probably due to a
>   conflict between plugins/theme. Try
>   deactivating all other plugins and
>   switching to the default theme.

Also, I have gotten this behavior when you have built your blog at something like mysite/blog and then moved it to simply mysite. You will need to edit the site base url in this case.